# How do I create pivot this way in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe df :-

| STORE | COL_APPLE_BB | COL_APPLE_NONBB | COL_PEAR_BB | COL_PEAR_NONBB | COL_ORANGE_BB | COL_ORANGE_NONBB | COL_GRAPE_BB | COL_GRAPE_NONBB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 28 | 24 | 24 | 32 | 26 | 54 | 60 | 36 |
| 2 | 19 | 12 | 24 | 13 | 10 | 24 | 29 | 10 |

I have another pyspark df `df2` :-

| STORE | PDT | FRUIT | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | APPLE | BB |
| 1 | 2 | ORANGE | NONBB |
| 1 | 3 | PEAR | BB |
| 1 | 4 | GRAPE | BB |
| 1 | 5 | APPLE | BB |
| 1 | 6 | ORANGE | BB |
| 2 | 1 | PEAR | NONBB |
| 2 | 2 | ORANGE | NONBB |
| 2 | 3 | APPLE | NONBB |

Expected pyspark `df2` with a column `COL_VALUE` for repective store,fruit,type:-

| STORE | PDT | FRUIT | TYPE | COL_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | APPLE | BB | 28 |
| 1 | 2 | ORANGE | NONBB | 54 |
| 1 | 3 | PEAR | BB | 24 |
| 1 | 4 | GRAPE | BB | 60 |
| 1 | 5 | APPLE | BB | 28 |
| 1 | 6 | ORANGE | BB | 26 |
| 2 | 1 | PEAR | NONBB | 13 |
| 2 | 2 | ORANGE | NONBB | 24 |
| 2 | 3 | APPLE | NONBB | 12 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 28, 24, 24, 32, 26, 54, 60, 36),
(2, 19, 12, 24, 13, 10, 24, 29, 10)
    ],
    ["STORE",   "COL_APPLE_BB", "COL_APPLE_NONBB",  "COL_PEAR_BB",  "COL_PEAR_NONBB",   "COL_ORANGE_BB",    "COL_ORANGE_NONBB", "COL_GRAPE_BB","COL_GRAPE_NONBB"]
)


df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 1,  "APPLE",    "BB"),
        (1, 2,  "ORANGE",   "NONBB"),
        (1, 3,  "PEAR", "BB"),
        (1, 4, "GRAPE", "BB"),
        (1, 5,  "APPLE",    "BB"),
        (1, 6,  "ORANGE",   "BB"),
        (2, 1,  "PEAR", "NONBB"),
        (2, 2, "ORANGE",    "NONBB"),
        (2, 3,  "APPLE",    "NONBB")
    ],
    ["STORE", "PDT", "FRUIT", "TYPE"]
)

unPivot_df = df.select("STORE",expr("stack(8, 'APPLE_BB',COL_APPLE_BB,\
                                                         'APPLE_NONBB',COL_APPLE_NONBB,\
                                                         'PEAR_BB', COL_PEAR_BB,\
                                                         'PEAR_NONBB', COL_PEAR_NONBB,\
                                                         'ORANGE_BB',COL_ORANGE_BB, \
                                                         'ORANGE_NONBB',COL_ORANGE_NONBB,\
                                                         'GRAPE_BB',COL_GRAPE_BB,\
                                                         'GRAPE_NONBB',COL_GRAPE_NONBB) as (Appended,COL_VALUE)"))  
    
df2 = df2.withColumn("Appended",concat_ws('_',col("FRUIT"),col("TYPE")))    
df2 = df2.join(unPivot_df,['STORE',"Appended"],"left")
df2.show()

+-----+------------+---+------+-----+---------+
|STORE|    Appended|PDT| FRUIT| TYPE|COL_VALUE|
+-----+------------+---+------+-----+---------+
|    1|ORANGE_NONBB|  2|ORANGE|NONBB|       54|
|    1|     PEAR_BB|  3|  PEAR|   BB|       24|
|    1|    GRAPE_BB|  4| GRAPE|   BB|       60|
|    1|    APPLE_BB|  1| APPLE|   BB|       28|
|    2|ORANGE_NONBB|  2|ORANGE|NONBB|       24|
|    2| APPLE_NONBB|  3| APPLE|NONBB|       12|
|    1|   ORANGE_BB|  6|ORANGE|   BB|       26|
|    1|    APPLE_BB|  5| APPLE|   BB|       28|
|    2|  PEAR_NONBB|  1|  PEAR|NONBB|       13|
+-----+------------+---+------+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Spark 3.2 or higher you could use something like:

```
data = data.melt(
    id_vars=['STORE'],
    value_vars=data.columns[1:], 
    var_name="variable", 
    value_name="value"
)
```

to get a "long" form of the dataset, and then use `regex_extract` twice to get the required information from the `variable` column.

For earlier versions of Spark, use the following:

```
def process_row(row):
    output = []
    for index, key in enumerate(row.asDict()):
        if key == "STORE":
            store = row[key]
        else:
            _, fruit, type = key.split("_")
            output.append((store, index, fruit, type, row[key]))
    return output


data = data.rdd.flatMap(process_row).toDF(
    schema=["STORE", "PDT", "FRUIT", "TYPE", "COLUMN_VALUE"]
)
```

Comment: how do we import `melt`? I see the latest availabe version is `3.3.1` ?

Comment: apologies, it is actually available from at least 3.2.0 and it is part of PySpark pandas: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.melt.html

Comment: but the other solution I gave will work for any version of Spark

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to `melt`, you can use `stack` in earlier Spark versions:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 28, 24),
        (2, 19, 12),
    ],
    ["STORE", "COL_APPLE_BB", "COL_APPLE_NONBB"]
)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 1, "APPLE", "BB"),
        (1, 2, "ORANGE", "NONBB"),
        (1, 2, "APPLE", "NONBB"),
        (2, 3, "APPLE", "NONBB")
    ],
    ["STORE", "PDT", "FRUIT", "TYPE"]
)
```

Create a column that matches the "COL_FRUIT_TYPE" in `df`:

```
df3 = df2.withColumn("fruit_type", F.concat(F.lit("COL_"), F.col("FRUIT"), F.lit("_"), F.col("TYPE")))
df3.show(10, False)
```

gives:

```
+-----+---+------+-----+----------------+
|STORE|PDT|FRUIT |TYPE |fruit_type      |
+-----+---+------+-----+----------------+
|1    |1  |APPLE |BB   |COL_APPLE_BB    |
|1    |2  |ORANGE|NONBB|COL_ORANGE_NONBB|
|1    |2  |APPLE |NONBB|COL_APPLE_NONBB |
+-----+---+------+-----+----------------+
```

Then "unpivot" the first `df`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

unpivotExpr = "stack({}, {}) as (fruit_type, COL_VALUE)".format(len(df.columns) - 1, ','.join(  [("'{}', {}".format(c, str(c))) for c in df.columns[1:]] ) )
print(unpivotExpr)
unPivotDF = df.select("STORE", expr(unpivotExpr)) \
              .where("STORE is not null")

unPivotDF.show(truncate=False)
```

The `stack` function takes as arguments: the number of "columns" that it will be "unpivoting" (here, it derives that it will be `len(df.columns) - 1`, as we will be skipping the STORE column); then, in case of just column, value pairs, it takes a list of these in the form col_name, value. Here, the
`[("'{}', {}".format(c, str(c))) for c in df.columns[1:]]` part takes columns from df, skipping the first one (STORE), then returns a pair for each of the remaining columns, such as 'COL_APPLE_BB', COL_APPLE_BB. In the end I join these into a comma-separated string (`",".join()`) and replace the placeholder `{}` with this string.
Example how `stack` function is usually called:
`"stack(2, 'COL_APPLE_BB', COL_APPLE_BB, 'COL_APPLE_NONBB', COL_APPLE_NONBB) as (fruit_type, COL_VALUE)"`

The `unPivotDF.show(truncate=False)` outputs:

```
+-----+---------------+---------+
|STORE|fruit_type     |COL_VALUE|
+-----+---------------+---------+
|1    |COL_APPLE_BB   |28       |
|1    |COL_APPLE_NONBB|24       |
|2    |COL_APPLE_BB   |19       |
|2    |COL_APPLE_NONBB|12       |
+-----+---------------+---------+
```

and join the two:

```
df3.join(unPivotDF, ["fruit_type", "STORE"], "left")\
   .select("STORE", "PDT", "FRUIT", "TYPE", "COL_VALUE").show(40, False)
```

result:

```
+-----+---+------+-----+---------+
|STORE|PDT|FRUIT |TYPE |COL_VALUE|
+-----+---+------+-----+---------+
|1    |2  |ORANGE|NONBB|null     |
|1    |2  |APPLE |NONBB|24       |
|1    |1  |APPLE |BB   |28       |
|2    |3  |APPLE |NONBB|12       |
+-----+---+------+-----+---------+
```

<s>The drawback is that you need to enumerate the column names in `stack`, if I figure out a way to do this automatically, I will update the answer.</s>

EDIT: I have updated the use of the `stack` function, so that it can derive the columns by itself.